# generate Google Chart using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, charts

I am working on a web application which retrieves JSON data from servlet and uses it to generate chart. I am successful in retrieving the requisite json file in Google Chart compliant JSON format but am unable to generate the chart.

The jsbin of google chart is in the foll link: http://jsbin.com/hofaqidape/1/watch?html,js,output

The data var should be generated using JSON and I am doing the following stuff in my servlet

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
            String json;
            newClass s =new newClass();
            List<newClass> classes = new ArrayList<newClass>();
            s.setCount(1);
            s.setName("Name");
            classes.add(s);
            s =new newClass();
            s.setCount(2);
            s.setName("Name1");
            classes.add(s);
            s =new newClass();
            s.setCount(3);
            s.setName("Name2");
            classes.add(s);
            s =new newClass();
            s.setCount(1);
            s.setName("Name4");
            classes.add(s);
            json="{ cols :[ {  label :  name  ,  type :  string },{ label :  count  ,  type :  number }], rows :[";
            String ss;int y;
            for(newClass class1:classes)
            {
                ss=class1.getName();
                y=class1.getCount();
                json+="{ c : [{ v : "+ss+" },{ v : "+y+"}]},";
            }
            json=json.substring(0, json.length()-1);
            json+="]}";
            JSONObject js=null;
            try {
                js = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                out.print(js);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

on the html side I have the foll code for my chart generation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                    url : "Serv",
                    dataType: 'json',
                     contentType: 'application/json',
                    success : function(result) {
                          var dat=result;
                          alert(JSON.stringify(dat));
                          google.load('visualization', '1', {
                                packages: ['corechart', 'bar']
                            });
                            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

                            function drawBasic() {

                                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(dat);

                                var options = {
                                    title: 'Motivation Level Throughout the Day',
                                    hAxis: {
                                        title: 'Name'
                                    },
                                    vAxis: {
                                        title: 'Count'
                                    }
                                };

                                var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
                                document.getElementById('chart_div'));

                                chart.draw(data, options);
                            }

                    },
            complete: function()
            {
                alert('done');
            }
                });
        });
```

alert(JSON.stringify(dat)) gives the alert as

> {"cols":[{"label":"name","type":"string"},{"label":"count","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Name"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"Name1"},{"v":2}]},{"c":[{"v":"Name2"},{"v":3}]},{"c":[{"v":"Name4"},{"v":1}]}]}

which is a valid JSON.

how do I generate the chart using this data just like I did in jsbin?

Comment: can you please tell why are you creating `drawBasic()` in `success` of ajax call? or to be more clear, why are you using everything in `ajax` call if it is set to execute on page load??

Comment: this was supposed to happen on an event linked with a drop down selection. I removed a large part of the code and is basically left with the important stuff onle. anyhow I need an ajax call for servlet calling from jsp, right?

Comment: Okay that is cool, without messing with your requirements, i have however posted my response. See if that helps you..

Answer (score 0):

`google.setOnLoadCallback()` set up a callback function to execute when Google Visualization API loaded, so `google.load` needs to load from the front explicitly. I am recalling it when i worked on them lately. My recommendation would be to move `google.load` and `drawBasic()` outside from `AJAX` call and use them in `success` of call, like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['corechart']
    });

    function drawBasic(d) {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(d);
      var options = {
         title: 'Motivation Level Throughout the Day',
         hAxis: {
            title: 'Name'
         },
         vAxis: {
            title: 'Count'
         }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url : "Serv",
        dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'application/json',
        success : function(result) {
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic(JSON.stringify(result)));
        },
        complete: function(){
           // whatever..
        }
    });

 });
```

**Update:** You only need to specify `packages: ['corechart']` which will define most basic charts, including the `pie`, `bar`, and `column` charts.

Comment: nothing happens and btw why should anything happen (nothing rude. just for knowledge!!). alerting d in drawbasic function does get me the same json file but still the contents are not shown

Comment: i haven't done anything with the argument `d` inside `drawBasic()` so don't expect any magic to happen there.

Comment: Oh i see, instead of `packages: ['corechart', 'bar']`, use the `packages: ['corechart']` which will handle all chart types. Check my update.

Comment: nope, nothing happens. its working in jsbin, should work here too. i have even tried <code>drawBasic(result)</code> instead of stringifying but still no output.

Answer (score 0):

finally got the answer to this question.
removed google.setOnLoadCallback() and called drawBasic() function from ajax call itself. somehow setOnLoadCallback() and $(document).ready() doesnt seem to coexist.

working code:

```
<script>
google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['corechart']
    });

    function drawBasic(d) {
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(d);
      var options = {
         title: 'Sample Data',
         hAxis: {
            title: 'Name'
         },
         vAxis: {
            title: 'Count'
         },
         width: 600,
         height: 240
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }  

                $(function(){
        $("#dd").change(function(){
            if($(this).val()!='null')
          {
                $.ajax({
            url : "Serv",
            data: {dd1:$(this).val()},
            dataType: 'json',
             contentType: 'application/json',
            success : function(result) {
              drawBasic(result);
            },
            complete: function(){
               // whatever..
            }
        })  ;
          }
            else
                {
                $("#chart_div").empty();
                alert('please select');
                }
        });
        });
    </script>
```